# 0 + 0 + 0... + 0 != 0

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a program that is finding paths in a graph and outputting the cumulative weight. All of the edges in the graph have an individual weight of 0 to 100 in the form of a float with at most 2 decimal places.

On Windows/Visual Studio 2010, for a particular path consisting of edges with 0 weight, it outputs the correct total weight of 0. However on Linux/GCC the program is saying the path has a weight of `2.35503e-38`. I have had plenty of experiences with crazy bugs caused by floats, but when would 0 + 0 ever equal anything other than 0?

The only thing I can think of that is causing this is the program does treat some of the weights as integers and uses implicit coercion to add them to the total. But 0 + 0.0f still equals 0.0f!
As a quick fix I reduce the total to 0 when less then 0.00001 and that is sufficient for my needs, for now. But what vodoo causes this?

**NOTE:** I am 100% confident that none of the weights in the graph exceed the range I mentioned and that all of the weights in this particular path are all 0.

**EDIT:** To elaborate, I have tried both reading the weights from a file and setting them in the code manually as equal to 0.0f  No other operation is being performed on them other than adding them to the total.

Comment: Can you construct a minimal test-case?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That is what I have been trying to do, so far with no luck. The amount of relevant code is too much to post but I will continue to try to reproduce the bug in a smaller scope. I was hoping there would be an obvious reasoning behind this.

Comment: I would recommend you look into the definition of machine epsilon. This seems to be whats causing your error here.

Comment: I presume this is Linux/x86?  32- or 64-bit mode?  If the former, try recompiling with `-march=native -mfpmath=sse`; this causes GCC to use a different set of floating-point instructions that are, er, less weird than the default set.  (`-mfpmath=sse` is the default for 64-bit mode.)

Comment: How are you confirming that the weights are actually zero in your test case? The ultimate test would be print and check their binary representation in hex, or perhaps do `assert(weight == 0.0f)`.

Comment: Do you have the "consistent math" setting enabled in your Windows/VS build? That could account for the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Perhaps intermediate expressions are of the form x * 0 where x is non-zero and these intermediate results are not exactly represented as 0? Heck, the compiler might even optimize explicit intermediate expressions such as 0 + ... + 0 (n times) as n * 0.

Comment: @EmileCormier I will try something of that sort and post the results.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Even if it did, why would the result be non-zero?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I have no idea! Just trying to narrow it down.

Comment: @rhalbersma: `x * 0 != 0` would violate the algebraic property that 0.0f is the zero element. I'd be very troubled if a platform would allow such a result.

Comment: Even with a path consisting of 5 nodes, the running total becomes off. I am still working on recreating some code that I can post.

Comment: Let's accept that `x * 0 == 0` for all x. If `sum(xi) != 0`, then there exists `xi != 0`. This can be proven by taking the contra-positive. I've therefore proven mathematically that one of the weights is actually not zero. :P

Comment: @EmileCormier I used a trivial loop to set all of the weights to 0. Now what is happening under the hood I can not control... But +1 for the silly proof.

Comment: @AustinHenley : Did you try disabling optimization (`-o0`)?

Comment: I'd bet one cent that you are adding at least one uninitialized variable.

Comment: @rodrigo While I never want to admit to such a thing, I will double check. Though it results in the same value every time I run it, rather than garbage.

Comment: @rodrigo Also, it correctly works on any other (nonzero) path that I have tested.

Comment: @AustinHenley - Uninitialized floats tend to have a null exponent and that gives them a value in the order of `1e-40` - `1e-30`. If you have any other non-null value in the path, then the uninitialized one would be negligible.

Comment: @rodrigo That is a very good point, I will check into that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's an IEEE floating point number, and it's not exactly equal to zero.

http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: But the question is: why?  (as in, why is it not zero?)  However, that's not possible to answer (yet), because we need to see a test-case from the OP.

Comment: I have studied floating points quite a bit in my undergraduate Numerical Analysis course but I have never found a case when 0 + 0 should ever be anything other than 0. I am never doing any other operation on it.

Comment: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm Why 0 is not 0? I think the "Zeros" section said that 0 is 0 and is precisely represented in the IEEE 754 rules.

Comment: Zero can be represented exactly in IEEE floats, so what baffles me is why arithmetic with only zeroes leads to a non-zero result.

Comment: This. Always use an epsilon when doing floating point comparisons. The answer to "why?" is probably because some of those edges don't have weights of exactly `0x00000000` but maybe something negligibly close to zero.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco I think your comment might be the truth, but dyffymo's answer is just too generic.

Comment: Looking at his answer, he states that he is not actually adding 0s, but numbers close to 0.  That explains his platform specific behavior.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan All of the numbers are 0, or at the least I am assigning 0.0f to them.

Comment: @Austin Henley: To clarify 0 + 0 is never anything other than 0 if by all 0s in the equation you mean `0x00000000`. You're just doing something wrong. In the best case scenario, you're invoking unspecified behavior somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco I will attempt to do some more testing to see what is going on at the bit level.

Comment: I don't know why but I have seen cases where code 0.0f == 0.0f produces false. I guess it's just a some sort of optimization.

Comment: Reduced the graph to a much more simple case and I am tracking the total through each iteration, it becomes slightly off from 0 very quickly. The testing continues

Comment: I believe the compiler - if it says 0 + 0 + 0 != 0, then one of those zeroes isn't.

Answer (score 5):

> [...] in the form of a float with at most 2 decimal places.

There is no such thing as a float with *at most 2 decimal places*. Floats are almost always represented as a binary floating point number (fractional binary mantissa and integer exponent). So many (most) numbers with 2 decimal places cannot be represented exactly.

For example, `0.20f` may look as an innocent and round fraction, but

```
printf("%.40f\n", 0.20f);
```

will print: 0.2000000029802322387695312500000000000000.

See, it does not have 2 decimal places, it has 26!!!

Naturally, for most practical uses the difference in negligible. But if you do some calculations you may end up increasing the rounding error and making it visible, particularly around 0.

Comment: I was aware of this for nonzero values, but my problem is arising when dealing with only 0s. However, for a large number of zeros being slightly off, maybe that is causing the problem as pointed out in another answer.

Comment: And how do you know that you are dealing exactly with 0's? Are they compiler constants? Read from a file?

Answer (score 3):

It may be that your floats containing values of "0.0f" aren't actually 0.0f (bit representation 0x00000000), but a very, very small number that evaluates to about 0.0. Because of the way IEEE754 spec defines float representations, if you have, for example, a very small mantissa and a 0 exponent, while it's not equal to absolute 0, it will round to 0. However, if you add these numbers together a sufficiently number of times, the very small amount will accumulate into a value that eventually will become non-zero.

Here is an example case which gives the illusion of 0 being non-zero:

```
float f = 0.1f / 1000000000;
printf("%f, %08x\n", f, *(unsigned int *)&f);
float f2 = f * 10000;
printf("%f, %08x\n", f2, *(unsigned int *)&f2);
```

If you are assigning literals to your variables and adding them, though, it is possible that either the compiler is not translating `0` into `0x0` in memory. If it is, and this still is happening, then it's also possible that your CPU hardware has a bug relating to turning 0s into non-zero when doing ALU operations that may have squeaked by their validation efforts.

However, it is good to remember that IEEE floating point is only an approximation, and not an exact representation of any particular float value. So any floating-point operations are bound to have some amount of error.

Comment: No, this is nothing like my case. I am NOT dividing, ever. I am only assigning 0 and 0.0f to variables and then adding them.

Comment: I am giving an example of what may cause the illusion. Of course, many different situations could cause something similar.

Comment: Right, I just never thought that adding constant 0s could cause this.

Comment: It is always possible that there is a bug in the particular hardware that you are using. Or, that the compiler is not assigning 0x0 to literals. Things like this have been known to squeak by (I believe there was one high-profile bug that got through on one of the older Pentium revisions, for example).

Comment: @sidran32: Whilst it's possible, it's vanishingly unlikely, when compared to all the other potential causes...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Of course. But if he ruled out everything else, it can end up being the ultimate reason. Back in high school I uncovered a CPU bug in a similar manner in my C++ class (confirmed by my teacher at the time). It sounded like he was nearing confidence that his code was unambiguous enough that other causes were likely ruled out. That's why I mentioned it.